# Printing a prompt variable in javascript returns "NaN"

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Printing a prompt variable in JavaScript returns "NaN".

Code:

```js
var topic = window.prompt("Topic:", "");
document.write(+ topic);
```

Comment: why `+` in write?

Comment: @NinaScholz if not, it would not return anything

Comment: Remove the `+`, it should work then.

Comment: No need to put "+" in document.write

Comment: It works now   ####

Comment: @F.Taylor, please do not change the question, because it invalids all answers.

Answer (score 3):

You use the `+` as [unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), which converts strings with a number to Number, but not strings, like `foo`, which are not convertable. Then you get [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), Not a Number.

```js
var topic = window.prompt("Topic:", "");
document.write('input: ' + topic);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your original question:

```
document.write(+topic);
```

`window.prompt` returns a string, and **unary** `+` operator **converts** a string to a number.

If you enter a non-numeric characters, they can't be converted to number, and you get `NaN`. If you type in a number, like `3`, you will get a number `3` outputted.

The solution to your problem is to simply remove `+`:

```
document.write(topic);
```

After you've edited a question, it works like this:

```
document.write('Topic ' + topic);
```

because now the **binary** `+` operator is used as a **concatenation** of strings, instead of converting to a number.